# Using dojo 1.8 in a packaged app (uncaught unload is not available in packaged apps)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After finally making some progress in using dojo with my packaged app, I've hit another road block that I can't find any documentation for.

```
{
  ...
  "sandbox": {
     "pages": ["test.html"]
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "background.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

test.html loads dojo from the app as well as some of my modules, but as dojo parses the dom of the page, I get an error thrown by the platformApp

```
Uncaught unload is not available in packaged apps. platformApp:14
(anonymous function)                               platformApp:14
Window.addEventListener                            platformApp:127
addListener                                        dojo.js.uncompressed.js:15317
on.parse
```

Are there any CSP rules I can add to the sandbox to let this do it's normal thing?

Comment: Could you share a small and self-contained repro? I would like to test and see if there is a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I will try to put something together and post it here soon.  I'm new to posting on stackoverflow, is there an accepted way to attach file examples to a question?

Comment: Here's a self contained example: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1YDS5-fQZJESGlNUFBMRHF3UTg

Comment: Thanks for the example, and I'm sorry it took so long to get back to you. Will answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish that chrome did this by default instead of throwing an error... but this is what I had to do before I loaded dojo:

```
// Prevent registrations for unload/beforeunload and warn, chrome will throw exception.
(function() {
  var windowAddEventListener = Window.prototype.addEventListener;
  Window.prototype.addEventListener = function(type) {
    if (type === 'unload' || type === 'beforeunload') {
          try {
        throw new Error('Do not use Window.addEventListener for ' + type);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message, e);
      }
    } else
      return windowAddEventListener.apply(window, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Comment: Is this a viable solution for a production level app? It seems the intent of the platform is to not allow the unload event and this circumvents that. I was having the same issue using jquery and signalr. This works for me but I would hate to rely on this and later have the Chrome team tighten the screws and break my code.

Comment: I don't see why not.  This still does not allow functional use of the API, it just fails (somewhat) quietly instead of breaking your application. Google's goals of making this API useless to devs are maintained and you shouldn't be relying on it (but now you have some time to fix your app, instead of being dead in the water)

Comment: Do we have any idea of the source of the error? I'm using Ember.js, and while the issue has no functional effect, at least for me, those error messages drive me crazy.

Comment: @Kincaid Yes.  There is a handler to check addEventListener on the window that will throw an uncaught exception if you try to register a listener on onunload.  Google does this intentionally because they do not want devs relying on that mechanism.  The above solutions prints the error to the console to avoid the app halting.  You can omit the console message if you like, I just don't like not logging errors.

Comment: @ddumont I guess my error is a bit different than yours. It stems from platformApp:14, but its "window.toolbar isn't allowed on package apps.", then going on to window.statusbar, window.scrollbars, etc. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear I can trace back the error further than platformApp:14.

Comment: @ddumont Thanks for the help. It appears I am able to trace it back.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, load and beforeload methods are disabled for packaged apps, and that applies to sandboxed iframes as well. You can check what else is disabled [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/platform_app.js).

Having said that, I just tried dojo 1.8 in a sandboxed iframe and, as long as I don't set unload listeners, the simple [Hello Dojo sample](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hello_dojo/) seems to work fine.

Comment: Hmm...  I actually wasn't doing much besides loading dojo.. possibly the parser and a content pane.

Comment: That's curious. Can you share the code you used that caused problems? Maybe Dojo has changed it, or maybe the sample I've used is too simple.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I think the demo is much too simplistic...  not much happens when you just load the base dojo file (all that's really happening when you load dojo.js and have async: true is that the amd loader loads...)

Comment: Try putting a dojo widget in there and have the parser come down to parse it.  I'm pretty sure you'll see that it sets up the onload hooks to provide useful modules like domReady module.