# Youtube API inside Chrome App

Tags: youtube-api, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to implement a chrome app in which I need to show a embed youtube video. 
I tried to use a sandbox html page which use the youtube iframe api but it failed. I got the follow error: Uncaught unload is not available in packaged apps. 
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: have you tried adding the code in this answer to the app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586394/using-dojo-1-8-in-a-packaged-app-uncaught-unload-is-not-available-in-packaged-a

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a webview. Simply take your embed code and swap the iframe tag for webview. No sandbox required :)

```
<webview width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZnuwB35GYMY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></webview>
```

Comment: The problems is that I need to control the video (start, pause, mute, etc). So I need to use the youtube api.

Comment: I spent a few hours trying that and gave up. I don't believe it is possible at this point.

Comment: I also spent several hours without success.

Comment: Well I'm trying to do this now and will let you know when I'm successful. :D